# how to use UTF-8 in PHP:json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, utf-8

I am getting data from MySQL and displaying in json format using php  but my data are in Persian language and it show `?` character instead of the original data
like given below.

> {"allnews":[{"id":"35","Onvan":"???? ???? ????? ????? ?????? ?? ???
>   ?????"},{"id":"36","Onvan":"?????????? ???? ? ???????????
>   ?????"},{"id":"37","Onvan":" ??????? ???? ??? ??? ???? ???? ?? ??? ??
>   ???? ???? ??????? ??? ?????? ???????? ?? "},{"id":"38","Onvan":" ?????
>   ????????? ???? ??? ?? ?? ??????? ????????"},{"id":"39","Onvan":"???
>   ???? ??? ????"}]}

Here is my code .Can you please check where has it gone wrong.

```
<?php
$hostname='localhost';
$username='xxxxxxxxx';
$password='xxxxxxxxx';
$response = array();
try {

    $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbtest",$username  ,$password);

    $response["allnews"] = array();

    /*** QUERY ****/
    $sql='SELECT * FROM test';

    $stmt=$dbh->query($sql);

    $objs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach($objs as $object) {
        $news = array();        
        $news["id"]=$object->id;
        $news["Onvan"]=$object->title;

        array_push($response["allnews"], $news);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

    /*** close connection ***/
    $dbh=null;

}catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: I have to ask, are you sure they are stored correctly in the database?

Comment: yes,http://ekhteraat.com/app/db.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Just before

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

And It also may be Mysql Fetching Error

So replace line

```
$dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbtest",$username  ,$password);
```

with

```
$dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbtest;charset=utf8",$username  ,$password);
```

Comment: do `print_r($response)` before `json_encode()`, if it is not readable then it's mysql fetching problem.

Comment: Returns --> Ø«Ø±ÙØª Ú©ÙØ§Ù ÙØ®ØªØ±Ø¹ Ø§Ø³Ù¾Ø±Û Ø¯Ø§ÙØ±Ø§Ù Ø¯Ø± Ø¬Ø§Ù Ø¬ÙØ§ÙÛ

Comment: replace line `$dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbtest",$username  ,$password);` with  `$dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbtest;charset=utf8",$username  ,$password);`

Comment: i replace but not work,Returns --> Ø«Ø±ÙØª Ú©ÙØ§Ù ÙØ®ØªØ±Ø¹ Ø§Ø³Ù¾Ø±Û Ø¯Ø§ÙØ±Ø§Ù Ø¯Ø± Ø¬Ø§Ù Ø¬ÙØ§ÙÛ

Comment: my corect data in db -> ثروت کلان مخترع اسپری داوران در جام جهانی |
print_r returns - > Ø«Ø±ÙØª Ú©ÙØ§Ù ÙØ®ØªØ±Ø¹ Ø§Ø³Ù¾Ø±Û Ø¯Ø§ÙØ±Ø§Ù Ø¯Ø± Ø¬Ø§Ù Ø¬ÙØ§ÙÛ 
| json_encode retern -> \u00d8\u00ab\u00d8\u00b1\u00d9\u0088\u00d8\u00aa \u00da\u00a9\u00d9\u0084\u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u0086 \u00d9\u0085\u00d8\u00ae\u00d8\u00aa\u00d8\u00b1\u00d8\u00b9 \u00d8\u00a7\u00d8\u00b3\u00d9\u00be\u00d8\u00b1\u00db\u008c \u00d8\u00af\u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u0088\u00d8\u00b1\u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u0086 \u00d8\u00af\u00d8\u00b1 \u00d8\u00ac\u00d8 ....

Answer (score 2):

**Best and simple solution**

```
$dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbtest",$username  ,$password);
```

**add charset to above line like ( mysql:charset=utf8mb4; )**

```
$dbh=new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=$hostname;dbname=dbtest",$username  ,$password);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use utf8_encode(String)

```
foreach($objs as $object) {
        $news = array();        
        $news["id"]=utf8_encode( $object->id);
        $news["Onvan"]=utf8_encode( $object->title);

        array_push($response["allnews"], $news);
    }
```